# Sqlalchemy mapped column boolean

Tags: sqlalchemy

There is a table:

```
from typing import Optional
from sqlalchemy import Boolean
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column

Base = declarative_base()

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[Optional[str]]
    link: Mapped[str]
    isenabled: Mapped[bool] = mapped_column(Boolean(), default=True)
```

I need that when creating an entry in the table, the "isenabled" field is created and filled in by default = True

in the current situation, when I try to insert an entry into the table, I get an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "isenabled" of relation "persons" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null, null, null, null, null, https://www.test.com/link/user_1/, null, null, 2023-12-31 13:42:58.973249, null, null)
```

At the same time, if I use a different ad style, then everything goes well (the entry is inserted, the "isenabled" field is filled in automatically as True)

```
persons = Table(
    "persons",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("link", String, nullable=False, comment="URL link"),
    Column("name", String, comment="Person's name"),
    Column("isenabled", Boolean(create_constraint=False), server_default=literal(True)),
)
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If the column definition specifies a value for `default` then the constraint is not violated.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Yes, your first example also works fine for me.  The exception you mention includes more columns than the example so maybe something else is going wrong in your original code.

Comment: Note that your ORM example (`class Person`) uses `default=` while your Core (`Table()`) example uses `server_default=`. They behave differently.